# Time dimension failed to follow extracted dates from imput individual pentad files names after merging them together

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray, netcdf4

I have multiple pentad netcdf (1482) files in a single directory with naming format precip_yyyymmd.nc (e.g., precip_2000061.nc). 'precip_' is common to all files in the directory as 'yyyy' indicate year, 'mm' indicate month and 'd' indicate number of pentad in the month mm. I only have six pentad in a single month and 247 months (from June 2000 to December 2020). I've been trying to merge all these file in the directory and I want the time dimension to contain the extracted dates (yyyy-mm-d) from all the files so that the will have 2000-06-01, 2000-06-02, 2000-06-3, 2000-06-3, 2000-06-4, 2000-06-5, 2000-06-6, 2000-07-01, 2000-07-02, 2000-07-03, 2000-07-04, 2000-07-05, 2000-07-06, 2000-08-01,...2020-12-06. My script worked to some extent but the date keeps overwriting one another. The time dimension only show dates instead of a total of 1482 dates as extracted from the files in the working directory

```
import xarray as xr
import os

# set the directory path where the files are stored
directory = '/home/wilson/Documents/PYTHON_TUTORIAL/Aggregated_Data_sum'

# get a list of all netCDF files in the directory
file_list = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if f.endswith('.nc')]

# create an empty list to store the xarray datasets
datasets = []

# loop over each file in the file list
for file in file_list:
    # load the netCDF file into an xarray dataset
    ds = xr.open_dataset(os.path.join(directory, file))
    # extract the year, month, and pentad from the file name
    year=int(file[7:11])
    month=int(file[11:13])
    pentad=int(file[13:14])
    # add the year, month, and pentad as a combined time coordinate  
    ds = ds.expand_dims(time=[f"{year:04d}-{month:02d}-pentad:02d}"])
    # append the dataset to the list
    datasets.append(ds)

# concatenate the list of datasets into a single xarray dataset along the 'time' dim
merged_ds = xr.concat(datasets, dim='time')

# sort the merged dataset by the 'time' dimension
merged_ds = merged_ds.sortby('time')

# save the merged dataset as a new netCDF file  merged_ds.to_netcdf(os.path.join(directory, f"merged_pentad.nc"))
```

print(ds) gives below information

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (Lon: 40, Lat: 20, time: 1)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) <U10 '2019-10-06'
  * Lon      (Lon) float64 -19.5 -18.5 -17.5 -16.5 -15.5 ... 16.5  17.5 18.5 19.5
  * Lat      (Lat) float64 0.5 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 ... 15.5 16.5 17.5 18.5 19.5
  Data variables:
     precip   (time, Lat, Lon) float32 nan nan nan nan nan ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Image below is the screenshot of the sample of files I want to merge/concatenate
[screenshot of the part of file in the working directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBFpw.png)

Comment: Sorry - there’s no way for us to help with this with the current information, and the scope of helping with this whole script is too much for a single question. Please change your question around to focus on one core issue. It seems like that should be getting the time dim right when reading in each file? If so, please diagnose where this is going wrong and ask about that. Make sure to include enough information for us to fully understand the problem. As a start, pasting the output of `print(ds)` as a code block would be helpful.

Comment: `print(ds)` would give you the info from the last iteration of your loop. what does `print(merged_ds)` give you?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The script actually worked to some extent but looking at the output of **print(ds)** and time dimension, I guess it keep overwriting the extracted date from the input files name instead of combining/joining them to have desire dates: **2000-06-01, 2000-06-02, 2000-06-3, 2000-06-3, 2000-06-4, 2000-06-5, 2000-06-6, 2000-07-01, 2000-07-02, 2000-07-03, 2000-07-04, 2000-07-05, 2000-07-06, 2000-08-01,...2020-12-06**

Comment: "but looking at the output of print(ds)" - Why are you looking at the output of print(ds) at all? You are overwriting ds in every iteration of your loop. Please edit your question to include the output of print(merged_ds).

Comment: Sure - sorry to steer off course here. I didn’t mean the variable `ds` specifically, I meant printing a dataset representation as a diagnostic is helpful for us generally so please use this to give us insight into what’s going wrong at various stages

Comment: @chris and Micheal Delgado, thank you for the information and sorry for the late reply. My script worked correctly and the mistake I made was using pyferret (using python and ferret code together) to opened the merged file. Thanks Again for the information.